# Create MultiIndex Based on number of spaces

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to work with a database ([this one](https://open.toronto.ca/dataset/neighbourhood-profiles/)) and I am not cable of multi-indexing correctly the data frame. Currently I have this:

```
csv_path='https://ckan0.cf.opendata.inter.prod-toronto.ca/download_resource/ef0239b1-832b-4d0b-a1f3-4153e53b189e?format=csv'
df_profile=pd.read_csv(csv_path,index_col=["Topic","Characteristic"])
#df_profile["Characteristic"]=df_profile.Characteristic.str.strip()
df_profile.drop(["_id","Data Source","Category"],axis=1,inplace=True)
df_profile.replace("No Designation","NaN",inplace=True)
df_profile.head(10)
```

[Result of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na9eq.jpg)

The problem is that some index are not inside of a column, and are represented by number of spaces. I mean, the first index inside the column has no space, then one division is created with one space in front of the space, and so on.

Here an example of one part obtained with df_profile.index.values.tolist()

```
('Mother tongue',
  'Mother tongue for the total population excluding institutional residents'),
 ('Mother tongue', '  Single responses'),
 ('Mother tongue', '    Official languages'),
 ('Mother tongue', '      English'),
 ('Mother tongue', '      French'),
 ('Mother tongue', '    Non-official languages'),
 ('Mother tongue', '      Aboriginal languages'),
 ('Mother tongue', '        Algonquian languages'),
 ('Mother tongue', '          Blackfoot'),
 ('Mother tongue', '          Cree-Montagnais languages'),
 ('Mother tongue', '          Eastern Algonquian languages'),
 ('Mother tongue', '          Ojibway-Potawatomi languages'),
 ('Mother tongue', '          Algonquian languages, n.i.e.'),
 ('Mother tongue', '        Athabaskan languages'),
```

Is there any function to convert this kind of structure in an multi-index of the dataframe based on the number of spaces? If not, what is the simplest method to solve this? Create a list of arrays with the different options (no spaces, one space, two spaces...) and add it to the index?

Thanks for your help.